# What version of package was installed by npm

Tags: angular, npm

**Summary**

I have questions about the basics of package.json vesions and npm (version 5.5.0). It boils down to these:

1. If my package.json includes dependency `"@angular/core": "^5.0.0"`,
   should `npm update` find and install `@angular/core@5.0.2`?
2. How do I determine which version of `@angular/core` is actually installed in
   my application?

**Details**

This issue started when I tried to install @angular/cdk, which is required by another package I want to install. When I run

```
npm i --save @angular/cdk
```

the output includes the following:

```
+-- @angular/cdk@5.0.0-rc0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@5.0.2
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@5.0.2
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@5.0.2
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/forms@5.0.2
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@5.0.2
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY typescript@2.5.3
```

But when I look at my package.json, I see the following items included in my dependencies:

```
"@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
```

and my devDependencies includes:

```
"typescript": "~2.5.0",
```

After searching the Net for info about npm and package.json versioning, I figured I need to run `npm upgrade` to get the latest version of all my packages. But I still get the UNMET DEPENDENCIES. Thus, my questions.

Thanks in Advance for any help.

Comment: have you tried `npm cache clean -f` before ?

Comment: @sancelot, I assume you mean before the running `npm upgrade`? I just ran the command (makes me nervous when it says, "I hope you know what you are doing' because I surely do not! ;) ). Then `npm uninstall @angular/cdk` followed by `npm i --save @angular/cdk`, and I get the same unmet dependencies.

Comment: Try adding "@angular/compiler-cli" to your devDependencies as well.

Comment: @JMatthews, It is already there as `"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0"`.

Comment: which version of npm are you using ?

Comment: @sancelot, I am using npm 5.5.0. (I have added this to the original question).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to verify which version of angular core running in your app. Open node_modules folder > @angular > open package.json. There you ll find details of angular version. Important note: "^5.0.0" means that you are telling node to install angular version 5 or greater then 5 which ever is available.

Comment: No package.json under @angular unless I go into a subfolder like /core. Which key shows me the version installed? I see `"raw": "@angular/core@^5.0.0"`, then further down I find `"_id": "@angular/core@5.0.2"`. If this is telling me I do have 5.0.2, why is it an UNMET DEPENDENCY?

Comment: At last node you can find version

Answer (score 0):

I think there are  some incompatibilities between global package and project's local package.

Here is the angular link for reference :
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli